# How can I use the UI router without changing the URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the angular UI state router using this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview. The router looks like this it has different urls for each state:

```
 // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // nested list with custom controller
        .state('home.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
            }
        })

        // nested list with just some random string data
        .state('home.paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },
                'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },
                'columnTwo@about': { 
                    templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
                    controller: 'scotchController'
                }
            }

        });
```

I would like to implement the UIrouter without changing the urls:at the moment the url changes when I change the state. Suppose I am trying to create a page where I have to add a parameter how can I pass on the parameter?

Comment: Use the router to do what? Question is incomplete

Comment: what you want to do with ui-router ?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to pass on a parameter from 1 state to another? do I have to use broadcast service or can I still use the UI router for that?

Comment: This sounds like an [*XY Problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe what you want to do, not how you *think* you should do it

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that. Only one way is custom implementation of routing. I made one time something like that. All containers for all subpages were fixed. Content was dynamically loaded using $http post. Changes were detected by listening of visible ID of container. A lot of stupid work. Most easier is to use ui - routing.